# Listen to changes and get info on updated fields only

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

I have Flutter/Firebase app, which allows users to store their book reading data into Firestore (books completed reading, reading currently etc). I would like to implement a feature, which allows users to see if someone completes reading a book (FS volume object field "completedUsers" updates) or someone starts reading a new book (FS account object field "nowReading" updates).

I think I should be using CollectionReference().snapshots().listen() - method for this, but I haven't figured out how and how to set it up with StreamBuilder, so I could get exact info on which part of db object was updated.

Here are my models on user account and volume:

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Account {
  String name;
  String uid;
  List<Volume> nowReading;
  List<Volume> wantToRead;
  List<Account> friends;
  Map<String, Volume> tips;

  Account(
      {this.name,
      this.uid,
      this.nowReading,
      this.wantToRead,
      this.friends,
      this.tips});

  factory Account.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$AccountFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AccountToJson(this);
}
```

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Volume {
  String id;
  String title;
  String description;

  String smallThumbnail;
  String bigThumbnail;

  List<String> authors;
  List<String> categories;

  int published;
  int pageCount;

  double averageGoogleRating;
  double averageUserRating;
  List<UserReview> userReviews;
  List<String> completedUsers;

  Volume(
      {this.id,
      this.title,
      this.description,
      this.smallThumbnail,
      this.bigThumbnail,
      this.authors,
      this.categories,
      this.published,
      this.pageCount,
      this.averageGoogleRating,
      this.averageUserRating,
      this.userReviews,
      this.completedUsers});

  factory Volume.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$VolumeFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$VolumeToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the following Flutterfire documentation section: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes?

Comment: Ah yes, I have. I can get info on which book/volume was updated, but question is how could I know which field was it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore notifies clients when a document has changed, but not what specific fields within that document have changed. If you application needs that information, you will have to compare the previous `DocumentSnapshot` and the new version yourself in your application code.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed to know.